# SpriteKit convertPointToView / convertPoint

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

**Question** How do I get the purple square to stay anchored at the bottom left of the screen regardless of the camera position?

**Details** I have an SKScene named colorScene that has a camera node and two shape nodes - one blue and one purple square. The camera is constrained to the blue square which is positioned at 0,0:

[image]

Now, say I want to position the purple square at the bottom left of the screen. And I want it to stay there no matter where the camera goes. First, I would make the purple square a child of the camera node. But then what? If I position the purple square at 0,0, strangely, it's in the middle of the screen. (Shouldn't the camera node be the entire screen area?) And if I try convertPoint to go from the camera node to the scene coordinates:

```
purpleNode?.position = convertPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), toNode: cameraNode!)
```

...things get even more mysterious:

[image]

Comment: You just need to position the purple node at -w/2 and -h/2

Comment: That will anchor the purple node to the bottom left. Add the purple node to the cameraNode, then set the purple node x=-w/2, y=-h/2

Comment: Your answer was so far from what I expected that it seemed impossible. (Plus I missed the tiny minus signs when I tried it the first time.) But you are right! My apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

> The scene is rendered so that the camera node’s origin is placed in the middle of the scene.

This should explain what you experienced

> If I position the purple square at 0,0, strangely, it's in the middle of the screen. (Shouldn't the camera node be the entire screen area?)

### Solution

Since we want to place `purple` on the bottom-left of the screen, we should start with the coordinate related to the view

```
let bottomLeftOfView = CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.height)
```

Next we need to convert these coordinate from the `view` to the `scene`

```
purple.position = convertPointFromView(bottomLeftOfView)
```

This is the full code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        let camera = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = camera
        addChild(camera)
        let purple = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square")
        purple.color = SKColor.purpleColor()
        purple.colorBlendFactor = 1

        let bottomLeftOfView = CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.height)
        purple.position = convertPointFromView(bottomLeftOfView)
        camera.addChild(purple)
    }
}
```

[image]

### Purple and anchorpoint

Only a quarter of the `purple` sprite is inside the screen. This because its `anchorpoint` is (0.5, 0.5): the center. So we just told SpriteKit to place the center of `purple` to the corner of the screen.

In order to have purple entirely into the screen we just need to tell SpriteKit to use use the `bottom left corner of purple` as `anchorpoint`

```
purple.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
```

[image]

### This is the final full code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)

        let camera = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = camera
        addChild(camera)

        let purple = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square")
        purple.color = SKColor.purpleColor()
        purple.colorBlendFactor = 1
        purple.anchorPoint = CGPointZero

        let bottomLeftOfView = CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.height)
        purple.position = convertPointFromView(bottomLeftOfView)
        camera.addChild(purple)

    }
}
```

Comment: No matter what I tried, I couldn't get your answer to work. Until I noticed my camera position. I had just tossed the camera node onto the scene (using the scene editor) not realizing that its position would affect other calculations. In fact, I mistakenly thought that because I had the camera constrained to a node, that I didn't need to worry about it. I also learned that SKView is a subclass of NSView, which explains why 0,0 is in the UPPER left corner. Many, many thanks!